# How copy file works in Windows OS?

Tags: windows

Maybe this is not 100% coding issue, but i hope someone can guide me to the right resources.

How copy operation works in Windows OS?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this one as currently worded -- can you be more specific?  How to copy a file?  What does it mean to copy a file?  How does Windows implement file copy operations?

Comment: I think this question should go in serverfault. It's not programming-related.

Comment: erratically: http://xkcd.com/612/

Comment: What I mean is, How windows handles the operation, process, etc... the low level details of the operation.

Comment: >>I think this question should go in serverfault. It's not programming-related.
Really!!! How comes that I need to implement copy procedure in my server application! But I don't want to relay on Windows API

Comment: What I really wanted is the stack details for the copy procedure.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Comment: +1 For funny cartoon, but doesn't really help him. :P

Comment: +1 For the funniest thing I'm likely to see this week

Comment: Coincidence this comic appeared today?

Answer (score 6):

Mark Russinovich posted an article that talks in detail about how file copying works in various modern [sic] versions of Windows in his blog entry [Inside Vista SP1 File Copy Improvements](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2008/02/04/2826167.aspx).

With source and target being on potentially different filesystems and potential problems with latency, the solutions turn out to be surprisingly complex. But the `CopyFileEx` API wraps it all up for you in a nice package.

Comment: Thanks, What I really wanted is the stack details for copy procedure.

Comment: Mark, maybe you should add that in the question.